# What is the address of L1 L2 LLC? (Cache memory)

Tags: caching, memory-management, io, memory-address, cpu-cache

I'm working on a project which touches subject of getting information from LLC (last level cache) and I'd started to wonder more about the memory addressing. When relating to memory most of the times we are relating to RAM, or drives like HDD,SSD with addresses, but what about memory address of Cache memory (L1,L2,LLC). Are their addresses are in the same address space? Or maybe I'm wrong to even think of cache addresses in the same way as in physical memory? If someone could explain this whole concept of I/O peripheral devices I would be glad!

Comment: From an application's perspective, it is not addressable or even accessible. It is encapsulated inside the processor itself.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you look up how the Memory Management Unit of the cache system in questions works. The cache addressing scheme is also important to learn. Anyway, here is a quick rundown of the basics. This is no way reflective of how the system in question works, but generally data is handled differently in a multi-level cache system than data is handled in physical memory. To fetch data from the cache, special cache addresses are used. The cache address is usually divided to multiple parts:

- Tag bits to identify the cache block being fetched/updated. Those are usually dependent on how many cache blocks your system can address at a time.
- Set bits (also names index bits) to identify the cache set where your block will be stored. This is where the data is stored inside the cache. If the cache is k-way associative, then the set bits tell you which set of cache ways your data block can be found, but will not tell you which way since that is largely decided by the replacement policy.
- Offset bits are usually only used directly by the CPU. The CPU requests an exact cache word to be fetched from memory. The offset bits tell which word in the cache block the CPU is looking for. It can be an instruction or a data word for processing. You would only think of offset bits when you look at a cache address of a cache directly connected to the CPU (L1 instruction or data caches).

Your LLC is most likely a k-way associative cache (LLC is rarely if ever of different cache structures like fully associative or direct mapped). Realistically speaking, the LLC should only be accessed for full data blocks (usually of 64-byte blocks, but can be bigger if the cache is larger) rather than specific cache words. Since RAM has full pages, once a data block is requested, your MMU will find which page that block belongs to and assigns it a unique tag and fetches it from RAM to LLC (this is extremely simplistic of how this processes transpires, but I hope you got the point).
Again, it would be best if you try to find out what the MMU is doing and how it is doing it. Cache addresses are not direct locations in the cache and work differently than physical addresses would.